# How can I make the output of my python script used for ansible dynamic hosts available to ansible

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to create a dynamic host for my ansible using python.
This is my python script which gets the AWS instance name and public dns value;

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
import json

def run_terraform():
    result = subprocess.run(["terraform",  "output", "-json"], capture_output=True, text=True, cwd="../terraform")
    result = json.loads(result.stdout)

    return result

def generate_ansible_inventory():
    terraform_outputs = run_terraform()
    instance_ips = terraform_outputs.get("instance_public_dns", {}).get("value", [])
    instance_names = terraform_outputs.get("instance_name", {}).get("value", [])
    master = []
    worker = []
    inventory = {}

    items = zip(instance_ips, instance_names)
    for item in items:
        if "master" in item[1]:
            master.append({"ansible_ssh_host":item[0], "ansible_ssh_user": "ubuntu", "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"})
        else:
            worker.append({"ansible_ssh_host": item[0], "ansible_ssh_user": "ubuntu", "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"})

    inventory["master"] = master
    inventory["workers"] = worker
    
    return print(json.dumps(inventory, indent=2))

# print(generate_ansible_inventory())
if __name__== "__main__":
   generate_ansible_inventory()
```

When I run the python script, this is the output;

```
vagrant@vagrant:~/fullstack-kanban-app/ansible$ python3 get_dns.py
{
  "master": [
    {
      "ansible_ssh_host": "ec2-54-165-95-159.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
      "ansible_ssh_user": "ubuntu",
      "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"
    }
  ],
  "workers": [
    {
      "ansible_ssh_host": "ec2-3-238-58-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
      "ansible_ssh_user": "ubuntu",
      "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I try to test the host file using this command `ansible all -i get_dns.py -m ping` this is what I get

```
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/vagrant/fullstack-kanban-app/ansible/get_dns.py with script plugin: unhashable type: 'dict'
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/vagrant/fullstack-kanban-app/ansible/get_dns.py with ini plugin: /home/vagrant/fullstack-kanban-
app/ansible/get_dns.py:3: Expected key=value host variable assignment, got: subprocess
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/vagrant/fullstack-kanban-app/ansible/get_dns.py as an inventory source
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
```

Please how can I resolve this?

Comment: The data structure you are outputting does not look like what Ansible expects to me. Have you looked at what an inventory script should provide in the documentation?  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#inventory-script-conventions

Comment: How do I then reference the ssh key file needed to connect to the ec2 instance. Any pointer?

Comment: Well, if your goal is to provide Ansible a list of AWS hosts, why don't you use the existing dynamic inventory, then? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_ec2_inventory.html

Comment: I think the problem is this line. Ansible expects the output to be in 
```python
return print(json.dumps(inventory, indent=2))
```
Try printing without return

Another thing that I think could be a problem is your inventory schema. Try adding _meta and hostvars as shown in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/first_inventory.html#verifying-the-inventory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want two groups "master" and "worker" which contain all your Kubernetes Master- and Workers-Nodes,
then populate your `inventory` dictionary like this:

```
def generate_ansible_inventory():
  (..)

  inventory = {
    "master": {
      "hosts": [],
    },
    "worker": {
      "hosts": [],
    },
    "_meta": {
      "hostvars": {},
    }
  }

  for item in items:
    if "master" in item[1]:
      inventory["master"]["hosts"].append(item[0])
      inventory["_meta"]["hostvars"][item[0]] = {"ansible_host": item[0], "ansible_user": "ubuntu", "ansible_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"}
    else:
      inventory["worker"]["hosts"].append(item[0])
      inventory["_meta"]["hostvars"][item[0]] = {"ansible_host": item[0], "ansible_user": "ubuntu", "ansible_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"}

  print(json.dumps(inventory, indent=2))
```

It produces this JSON output, which is a valid inventory:

```
{
  "master": {
    "hosts": [
      "ec2-54-165-95-159.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    ]
  },
  "worker": {
    "hosts": [
      "ec2-3-238-58-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    ]
  },
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "ec2-54-165-95-159.compute-1.amazonaws.com": {
        "ansible_host": "ec2-54-165-95-159.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        "ansible_user": "ubuntu",
        "ansible_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"
      },
      "ec2-3-238-58-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com": {
        "ansible_host": "ec2-3-238-58-66.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        "ansible_user": "ubuntu",
        "ansible_private_key_file": "kanban.pem"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `ansible_ssh_*` vars are deprecated as of Ansible 2.0. They should be `ansible_*`.

**UPDATE** (Regarding the question about "`_meta`" key and loading from static files):

The inventory format expected by the [YAML plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yaml_inventory.html)
is a little different from the JSON format that the [Script plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_inventory.html) expects.

I didn't find a reference for the JSON format online, but you can see it for an existing inventory, if you run `ansible-inventory --list`.
(This is the way you should test your inventory anyway, not with `ansible -m ping`)

What happened, when you dumped your script's output to a file and loaded that file with `-i`, was that the YAML plugin did the job. The `YAML plugin` is smart enough to load JSON too, but with a different format than the `Script plugin` uses.

- If you run

  ```
  ansible-inventory --list -i myfile.json -vvv
  ```

  you will see a debug line, that says `Parsed (..)/myfile.json inventory source with yaml plugin`. So it's the YAML plugin at work.
- If you run

  ```
  ansible-inventory --list -i myfile.py -vvv
  ```

  you will see `Parsed (..)/myfile.py/myfile.py inventory source with script plugin`.

Comment: This works like magic. I recreated another python script whose output which when I copy to another file and run as the inventory it works, but whenever I run the script directly with `ansible -m ping` command I get errors. I noticed you used `"_meta": {"hostvars": {},}` in yours and I think that is the solution, because in my script there was nothing like that. Please can you explain the use of `"_meta": {"hostvars": {},}` that you implemented? Thank you once again.

Comment: I added an update regarding "`_meta`" in my answer.